# How do I find the parameters for a best-fit-model of a sine-function?

Tags: r, statistics

My professor is asking me to use fitModel and coef to find the best model for a data set. I'm trying to find the correct A, P, h and v value and then plot the line-of-best-fit over my conjectured model.

This is the code that I am trying:

```
plotPoints(People~Year, data = HispanicPopulation)

plotFun(25 * sin((2*pi/80) * (People-1990)) + 30~People, col="blue", add=TRUE)
```

and the picture is the result that I got out of it.
[image]

This is the code that I am using to try to get the values of A,P,h, and v for the line-of-best-fit.

```
bestSinusoidalModel=fitModel(
Year~25*sin((2*pi/80)*(People-1990))+30,
data=HispanicPopulation,
start = list(A=25,P=80,h=1990,v=30)

coef(bestSinusoidalModel)
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is quite a lot to correct.
First let's generate a sample dataset (I assume that a) you have been given one but there is no data in your question and b) the dependant variable is `People`, not `Year`):

```
set.seed(0)
year <- seq(1970, 2010, 1)
HispanicPopulation <- data.frame(Year = year,
                                 People = 25*sin((2*pi/80)*(year-1990))+30 + rnorm(length(year))
)
```

The plotted points:
[image]

Second we need to correct the model formula inserting coefficients `A`, `P`, `h`, `v` and exchanging `Year` and `People`. The script will be the following:

```
library(mosaic)
bestSinusoidalModel <- 
fitModel(
  People~A*sin((2*pi/P)*(Year-h))+v,
  data=HispanicPopulation,
  start = list(A=25,P=80,h=1990,v=30)
)
```

The model is fitted:

```
function (Year, ..., transformation = function (x) 
x) 
return(transformation(predict(model, newdata = data.frame(Year = Year), 
    ...)))
<environment: 0x000002ab69109c40>
attr(,"coefficients")
         A          P          h          v 
  25.10064   80.13542 1990.47180   30.67378 
attr(,"class")
[1] "nlsfunction" "function"
```

Coefficients of our model are the following:

```
> coefficients(bestSinusoidalModel)
         A          P          h          v 
  25.10064   80.13542 1990.47180   30.67378
```

Third. We can plot the curves (blue solid for our generator function) and red dashed for fitted model:

```
plotFun(25 * sin((2*pi/80) * (Year-1990)) + 30~Year, col="blue", add=TRUE)
plotFun(bestSinusoidalModel, col="red", lty = 2, add=TRUE)
```

[image]